# lua script return false is giving error "redis: nil" during the EvalSha

Tags: go, redis, lua

I am writing a small example to explain the issue I am facing:

```
func (rc *redisClient) runDummyScript(ctx context.Context) bool {
    scriptSha, err := rc.ScriptLoad(ctx, dummyScript).Result()
    if err != nil {
        return false
    }

    rs, err := rc.EvalSha(ctx, scriptSha, []string{}).Result()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print("could not execute the redis commands for ", err)
    }
    ans, _ := rs.(bool)
    return ans
}

const dummyScript = `return false`
```

for cases when the script is returning true, the above method `runDummyScript` isn't giving any error. But for cases when the script is returning false, this gives me an error `"redis: nil"`.

I think this is happening because the lua script is converting `false` to `nil` and hence, `EvalSha` is treating an nil return from the script as an error, which seems weird to me.

To work this out, I have to ignore the `"redis: nil"` errors, which will be again weird for me. But a lua script returning boolean seems pretty common operation, writing a work around doesn't seem a good option to me.

I am curious to know how to make this work properly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

'I think this is happening because the lua script is converting false to nil and hence, EvalSha is treating an nil return from the script as an error, which seems weird to me.'

No - Redis do this.
With Lua you can return as much values/datatypes as you wish.
But Redis seems to handle only numbers (integer?) and string and (EDIT) table DT.
A simple Test...

```
€ redis-cli 
127.0.0.1:6379> eval 'return(true)' 0
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> eval 'return(false)' 0
(nil)
127.0.0.1:6379> eval 'return {1, 2.5, 3.14159265, true, false}' 0
1) (integer) 1
2) (integer) 2
3) (integer) 3
4) (integer) 1
5) (nil)
127.0.0.1:6379> eval 'return {1, "2.5", "3.14159265", "true", "false"}' 0
1) (integer) 1
2) "2.5"
3) "3.14159265"
4) "true"
5) "false"
```

Now pure Lua (5.1)

```
€ /bin/lua
Lua 5.1.5  Copyright (C) 1994-2012 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
2.5
> return(table.remove({1, 2.5, 3.14159265, true, false}, math.random(1, 5)))
true
> return(table.remove({1, 2.5, 3.14159265, true, false}, math.random(1, 5)))
true
> return(table.remove({1, 2.5, 3.14159265, true, false}, math.random(1, 5)))
false
> return(table.remove({1, 2.5, 3.14159265, true, false}, math.random(1, 5)))
1
> return(table.remove({1, 2.5, 3.14159265, true, false}, math.random(1, 5)))
2.5
> return(table.remove({1, 2.5, 3.14159265, true, false}, math.random(1, 5)))
true
> return(table.remove({1, 2.5, 3.14159265, true, false}, math.random(1, 5)))
2.5
> return(table.remove({1, 2.5, 3.14159265, true, false}, math.random(1, 5)))
3.14159265
```